# How can I go about switching from eth to geth while keeping my same accounts?

Tags: go-ethereum, cpp-ethereum, keystore

I'd like to move my accounts from the eth client to geth. Also, I'd like to keep the same addresses. Is this possible?

Comment: This is an exact duplicate and you even include the original in your answer. Why creating a new thread? I'm tempted to merge your answer to the other question.